# when parent directory is mounted on to new volume, i cannot see the sub directory which was existing earlier

Tags: command-line, permissions, mount, bashrc, bash-history

After mounting `/yesh` onto a new volume, I cannot see the sub directory `/yesh/data001` which was existing before mounting.

If the sub directory is existing where can I find it?

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more? Are you saying that the directory `/yesh/data001` was present _before_ mounting a _new_ volume onto `/yesh`?

Comment: That's how it is supposed to work. Always mount on an empty directory.

Comment: @Mr Shunz  yes /yesh/data001 was present before mounting

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `mount --bind` for seeing old mount you have on same mount point.

Create any directory in your filesystem, ex: /mnt/data001, then

command: `mount --bind /yesh/data001 /mnt/data001`

This is tricky case, you cannot see old mount and you cant `umount` your old mount. Generally `restart` is kind of solution but with out restart if you want to access `/yesh/data001` I believe you can achieve via above command.